# Performance tuning on matching strings between two tables columns

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have two tables:

Table 1: Is the filtered or I can say the staging table with contains the filtered records, maybe in millions or in singles records.

Table 2: Is the table with the all inserted data which is of more than hundred millions of records.

Note: Both the tables having more than 40 columns and having index on the required columns.

The following is the sample data to understand the requirement.

```
create table pattern1 ---This is staging table
(
  col1 varchar(100)
);

insert into pattern1 values('John Mak'),('Omont Boy'),('Will Smith'),('Mak John');

create table pattern2
(
 col1 varchar(100)
);  

insert into pattern2  values('John Mak'),('Smith Will'),('Jack Don');
```

**Expected result**:

```
 col1
 ----------
 John Mak
 Smith Will
```

Explaination of expected result: The matching result should in the result it may be in any sequence like `Smith Will` and `Will Smith` should display.

**Query**:

```
SELECT p2.* 
FROM Pattern2 P2
INNER JOIN Pattern1 P1 ON P2.col1 LIKE '%'||P1.col1||'%' 
--May required more than one columns here to match strings.
```

The above query took more than 20 minutes and keeps running on hundred millions of records. Any other approache search strings?

Comment: I would try to make sure, by updating columns, that `select col1 from pattern1 intersect select col1 from pattern2;` can work...

Comment: @marcus, There will be different condition in the `ON` clause. For example `LIKE '%'|| p1.col1` or `LIKE p1.col1||'%'`

Comment: You can experiment with a trigram index on the large table, but it sounds like this will always be slow.